# How to send current user_id to Sentry scope.user()?

Tags: python, error-handling, sentry

Project is in PYTHON 
I want to log all current users affected by some random "IndexError" (For instance) error. 
Currently when I try to do this:

```
from sentry_sdk import push_scope, capture_exception
            with push_scope() as scope:
                scope.user = {"email": user.email}
                capture_exception(ex)
```

it sets first user's email and that doesn't change with other users facing the same error.

I want to see all users who were affected by that error.

Comment: I assume this user object belongs to some web framework. Which one is it?

Comment: web framework used here is pylons!